# Why Extend Volume is Grayed Out in Server 2016?

Tags: windows, disk-volume, extend

I can't expand my Simple Volume Disk0 for C:\ Volume.

This is Server 2016 Virtual Machine, Unallocated space of 300GB was added to the VM Disk, as you can see in the screenshot. I haven't the option "Extend Volume" on the C-drive. On the D-drive the option "Extend Volume" is working fine.

Any suggestions please?

[C-drive extend grey out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfqES.png)

[Disk overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1toq.png)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Dynamic disks? Many disk utilities will not move those.

Comment: Any reason you are still on Server 2016? It was EOL 1/2022.

Comment: @java-addict301 win2016 extended support goes to Jan 12, 2027.  So there's no new work, only security fixes.

Comment: @Criggie, how many will subscribe for extended support? 5-10%...

Comment: @RomeoNinov I may have used the wrong name, sorry.   Win2016 still gets security fixes until Jan2027 and support after that date would be chargeable support.

Answer (score 6):

You can only extend a volume into adjacent free space. The C: volume has no adjacent free space. The free space is adjacent to the D: volume.

You could use a third party utility (take your pick) to make the changes needed to extend the C: volume.

Comment: That's not exactly true for Dynamic disks – LDM can concatenate several chunks into a single partition, like Linux LVM.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because the free space is not exactly after the volume you want to extend. If you can move the volume D to be on the right of disk and then extend volume C